# WOKRSPACE value not defined in concurrent builds

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Scenario: 2 builds running concurrently. The configuration is set up to allow concurrent builds when possible.

I am seeking to find the most probable cuase for the finding that is, the `WORKSPACE` variable seems available so the clone of a project works. Any subsequent builds occuring
seem to be provided the value `********` instead of the value the WORKSPACE variable is assigned to.

Please read for details.

#### Build 1

The first build thats instantiated contains the correct path from which the git clones the project:
Look at the command from `git clone --branch` onwards.

#### log

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace/target && git clone --branch app-00.00.00.002 file:///var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace/target/checkout

#### Build 2

Problem found in log below:
Look at the command `git clone --branch` onwards and notice that the asteriks. WORKSPACE is an variable provided by jenkins whos value in my case for the job is `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace`.

If you replaced the `*******` from the below log with the value assigned to the WORKSPACE variable, you would get `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace@2/target/checkout`. This would be the corrct directory the project should be cloned into.
Therefore, the error would not occur.

#### log

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp-build-job/workspace@2/target && git clone --branch app-00.00.00.002 file:********@2/target/checkout

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project app: could not perform a local checkout -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought it may be something to do with jenkins not injecting the variable to subsequent builds.

After much hair loss, I figured out that the `@` symbol, which is the default separator is not escaped when included in the path. That is why I was seeing the ****

#### Solution

Change the default separator value.

#### How?

On the jenkins server, 
debian:  open the file `/etc/default/jenkins`
RHEL: open the file `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Find the variable `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`

Add the following to it `-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=SomeSeperatingName`

Of course, `SomeSeperatingName` can be anything you want. Just not a character that needs to be escaped

Then, restart jenkins